# Create and optimize mysql query, php

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Having trouble to create quality and optimize mysql query.
Lets create a table with values.

```
CREATE TABLE flow
(
 US1 varchar(20), 
 US2 varchar(30)
);

INSERT INTO flow
(US1, US2)
VALUES
('rasim', 'tere1'),
('rasim', 'tere2'),
('rasim', 'tere3'),
('rasim', 'tere4'),
('tere1', 'tere5'),
('tere1', 'tere6'),
('tere2', 'tere7'),
('tere3', 'tere8'),
('tere3', 'tere9'),
('tere4', 'tere10'),
('tere5', 'tere11'),
('tere5', 'tere12'),
('tere9', 'tere13'),
('tere9', 'tere14');
```

What i am trying to achieve:

```
$firstUs = DB::query("SELECT US2 FROM `flow` WHERE US1='rasim'");

while($first = DB::fetch($firstUs)):

$second =(int) // select and count(US2) foreach value where US1 = $first['US2'];

$third =(int) //select and count(US2) foreach value where US1 = $second['US2'];

$four = (int) //select and count(US2) foreach value where US1 = $third['US2'];

endwhile;
```

$firstUs = returns 4 values ( tere1, tere2, tere3, tere4 ). I whant the script to count for each of these values, the number of entries from US1. $second = returns 2 values ( tere5, tere6 ). Count value would be (2) on first php while loop.
How to create a good mysql script so that this will work and if there would be a lot of users accsesing this page, the server wont crash and speed of the query would be much less.

Thank you

I am traying to achieve a pyramid scheme. Where 'rasim' is the primary user name. Where $second , $third and $four is a int number of users per level. $second will have caount of all users in the second level of the pyramid.

[Example image how it will look like. http://silverstream.ee/img/stack.PNG](http://silverstream.ee/img/stack.PNG)

Comment: Anybody ? Is here a MySQL guru ?

Comment: Still have problems. If anyone have some idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's something like:

```
select f2.us1, count(f2.us2)
from flow f1
inner join flow f2
f1.us2=f2.us1
where f1.us1='rasim'
group by f2.us1
```

I hope this is what you want.

Comment: ITs not that simple. As far as i know, i must do lots of loops. 1) while 2) foreach 3) foreach 4) foreach. Every loop insede each other. That is unsafe.

Comment: ok, then i didn't understand the problem.. you want the count for each US1 = (select US2 where us1='rasim')?

Comment: What actually he wants, he wants to fetch count of US2 and data where US1 should be 'rasim' and if then retrieved data will go for check whether any US1 column having record containing retrieved US2. Am I right @RasimMehtijev?

Comment: Sorry but That didnt help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option here would be to break the data out into separate tables so that you don't have the Primary Key (US1) be relational to the "Foreign Key" (US2) within the same table. Then you could accomplish what you are trying to do with a query as opposed to numerous loops.

Unfortunately I still have no idea what exactly you are trying to accomplish so it's impossible for me to create an example scenario with what you've given.

Comment: I edited the question. Bellow is description of what i am trayng to get. Tank you